# What is the difference between window.onload = init(); and window.onload = init;

Tags: javascript, scripting

From what I have gathered, the former assigns the actual value of whatever that functions return statement would be to the onload property, while the latter assigns the actual function, and will run after the window has loaded. But I am still not sure. Thanks for anyone that can elaborate.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the difference.

Comment: SInce you gave the correct definition, we don't really know what you're not sure about. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Well the book I am reading said there is a distinct difference, but to me it accomplishes the exact same thing. The function runs after the page loads, what is the point of using either one?

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill—The OP wants an answer of "yes" or "no" and if no, why.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
window.onload = init();
```

assigns the onload event to whatever is **returned** from the init function when it's executed.  `init` will be executed **immediately**, (like, **now**, *not* when the window is done loading) and the result will be assigned to `window.onload`.  It's unlikely you'd ever want this, but the following would be valid:

```
function init() {
   var world = "World!";
   return function () {
      alert("Hello " + world);
   };
}

window.onload = init();
```

---

```
window.onload = init;
```

assigns the onload event to the function init.  When the onload event fires, the init function will be run.

```
function init() {
   var world = "World!";
   alert("Hello " + world);
}

window.onload = init;
```

Comment: Any examples on when to use which?

Comment: That makes sense, but I guess my question would be, what is the difference between the declaration without the () and the one without? Because both just run when the window is done loading.

Comment: @Andy - there's a significant difference - I've elaborated my answer

Comment: @Andy: NO, NO, NO, NO, NO!!!!!!! The one without the parentheses runs the function when the window is through loading. The one *with* the parentheses runs the function right when the assignment is done, like perhaps while the HEAD of the page is being evaluated.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't refresh the page when I put the 2nd comment. You have elaborated Thank you very much.

Comment: @Gaurav Gupta - the _only_ reason to use `window.onload = init()` is when `init()` returns another function. If you just want to run a function immediately then call it directly. The whole point of `.onload` (or `.onclick` or any other event handler) is that you give it a function reference so that that function can be run at some point in the future when the event occurs.

Answer (score 5):

```
window.onload = foo;
```

assigns the value of *foo* to the onload property of the window object.

```
window.onload = foo();
```

assigns the value returned by calling *foo()* to the onload property of the window object. Whether that value is from a return statement or not depends on *foo*, but it would make sense for it to return a function (which requires a return statement).

When the load event occurs, if the value of *window.onload* is a function reference, then window's event handler will call it.

Answer (score 2):

Good answers, one more thing to add:

Browser runtimes ignore non-object (`string, number, true, false, undefined, null, NaN`) values set to the DOM events such as window.onload. So if you write `window.onload` = 10 or any of the above mentioned value-types (including the hybrid `string`) the event will remain `null`.

What is more funny that the event handlers will get any object type values, even `window.onload = new Date` is a pretty valid code that will prompt the current date when you log the `window.onload`. :) But sure nothing will happen when the `window.load` event fires.

So, always assign a function to any event in JavaScript.