# Javascript glitch updating value of input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on an HTML page that uses Morris.js to create charts. I added calendar widgets to allow the user to choose a start and an end date, and a button to update the data. I realized it would be convenient if I automatically set the dates to "today" so the charts already have data when first loaded. Everything is working fine: the dates are set to today, the queries return valid JSON, and the charts display the correct data. However, the `<input>` fields are not updated and I can't figure out why. Also worth noting, **after pressing the button on "empty" fields, the dates are correctly set and DO appear in the inputs afterwards**. Here is the relevant code:

```
<script> // inside head tag
  function updateCharts() {
    startDate = document.getElementById("startDate").value;
    endDate = document.getElementById("endDate").value;
    scale = document.getElementById("scale").value;
    console.log("before " + startDate);
    if (startDate == "") {
        console.log("empty start");
        var today = new Date;
        startDate = today.getFullYear() + "-" + 
                    (today.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + // getMonth in range [0,11]
                    5;//today.getDate();
        document.getElementById("startDate").value = startDate;
        console.log("input " + document.getElementById("startDate").value);
    }
    if (endDate == "") {
        console.log("empty end");
        endDate = startDate;
        document.getElementById("endDate").value = endDate;
        console.log("output " + document.getElementById("endDate").value);
    }
    console.log("after " + startDate + " " + endDate);
    var charts = ['providers', 'variance', 'cities', 'convertions', 'unique_ids'];
    var len = charts.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var chartType = charts[i]
        chart(chartType, startDate, endDate, scale);
    }
  }
</script>
```

Here are the input tags:

```
<div id="dates" class="row">
    <p>From: <input type="text" id="startDate" /> 
        To: <input type="text" id="endDate" />
        <select id="scale">
            <option value="0">Hour</option>
            <option value="1">Day</option>
            <option value="2">Month</option>
        </select>
        <button value="Show" onclick="updateCharts()">Show</button>
    </p>
</div>
```

And my script at the end of the body to call the function:

```
<script>
    window.onload = updateCharts();
</script>
</body>
```

The console output after the load, before pressing the button:

```
before 
index.html (line 41)
empty start
index.html (line 43)
input 2015-11-5
index.html (line 49)
empty end
index.html (line 52)
output 2015-11-5
index.html (line 55)
after 2015-11-5 2015-11-5
```

So as you can see the value is (correctly?) set and retrieved by Javascript after the conditionals, but it is not shown in the browser.

Comment: The values seems to be set in JSFiddle, probably the problem somes from somewhere else. See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ddan/poygkzxn/

Comment: I see it works in the fiddle, I don't understand how the value can be seen by the console but not the fields. I tried Safari, Firefox, and Chrome, so it's not a browser issue either. I'm out of ideas on what could be wrong :(

Comment: Look for javascript errors in console. If an error happened before updating, the value won't be set.

Comment: Why the jQuery tag? I see none.

Comment: There are no erros or warnings at all . @j08691 I also tried the jQuery way of setting values `$('#startDate').val(startDate);` and had it commented out, I forgot I actually deleted them.

Comment: Try substituting `window.onload = updateCharts` for `window.onload = updateCharts();`

Comment: Wow! That did it! What is the difference between using and not using the `()`? Thank you so much @guest271314!

Comment: `window.onload = updateCharts` references `updateCharts` as function to call at `onload` event ; `window.onload = updateCharts()` calls `updateCharts()` function when reached in `js`

Comment: I see, so the reason the text wasn't set could be that the function was being called before the input elements were properly loaded? Also, please add your comment as an answer so I can accept it in case someone comes across this. Again, thank you so much! @guest271314

Comment: @gamda _"so the reason the text wasn't set could be that the function was being called before the input elements were properly loaded?"_ Yes , see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830074/what-is-the-different-between-window-onload-init-and-window-onload-init

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try substituting `window.onload = updateCharts` for `window.onload = updateCharts();`

See [GlobalEventHandlers.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) , [What is the different between window.onload = init(); and window.onload = init;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830074/what-is-the-different-between-window-onload-init-and-window-onload-init)