# JavaScript/jQuery function skipping code with window load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a made a function that'd apply some css rules to elements on window load. Here is my code.

```
function applyHover()
{

        $('.view_preloader .overlay').css('opacity',1);

        $('.view_preloader .s2').css({

            '-webkit-transform' : 'translate3d(59px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-45deg)',
            '-moz-transform': 'translate3d(59px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-45deg)',
            '-o-transform': 'translate3d(59px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-45deg)',
            '-ms-transform': 'translate3d(59px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-45deg)',
            'transform': 'translate3d(59px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-45deg)'             

        });

        $('.view_preloader .s3, .view_preloader .s5').css({

            '-webkit-transform' : 'translate3d(59px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,90deg)',
            '-moz-transform': 'translate3d(59px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,90deg)',
            '-o-transform': 'translate3d(59px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,90deg)',
            '-ms-transform': 'translate3d(59px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,90deg)',
            'transform': 'translate3d(59px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,90deg)'              

        });     

        $('.view_preloader .s4').css({

            '-webkit-transform' : 'translate3d(59px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-90deg)',
            '-moz-transform': 'translate3d(59px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-90deg)',
            '-o-transform': 'translate3d(59px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-90deg)',
            '-ms-transform': 'translate3d(59px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-90deg)',
            'transform': 'translate3d(59px,0,0) rotate3d(0,1,0,-90deg)'             

        });     

        alert(); //Only for testing purpose                             
}
```

Now, as per the requirements, i need to call this function when window is fully loaded. Here is it.

```
$(window).load(function(e) {
    applyHover();
});
```

But when window loads, what it does, it only triggers the alert function written at the end of code and skips all the code that is ought to apply the css.

Strange thing is that when i call the very same function by another event like clicking on another element, it totally works fine. For example

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $('.text').click(function(e) {
       applyHover();
   });

});
```

So i guess the problem has something to do with window load. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the DOM hasn't been created yet when the window.onload event is triggered - you should move your call inside the ready function. Or try body.onload like mentioned here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp

Take a look here: [window.onload seems to trigger before the DOM is loaded (JavaScript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485244/window-onload-seems-to-trigger-before-the-dom-is-loaded-javascript)
this goes over your problem

Comment: Not exactly what i was looking but still, it helped me finding light..thank you

Answer (score 0):

`window.onload` != `document.ondomcontentloaded`. Try putting it in the latter instead:

```
$(function() {
    applyHover();
});
```

(This is short-hand syntax for `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`.)