# How to execute javascript function from code-behind but only after the page loads

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

I've found other solution on how to executes a javascript function from code-behind. The problem is that it firing before the page loads, so I can't add logic to it.

```
if(result)
{
   Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), 
                                               "Script", "confirmPwdChange();", true);
}
```

On the client side

```
<script>
   confirmPwdChange()
   {
     alert("Password has been successfully changed.");
     //Add more logic here, after user clicks the OK button...
   }
</script>
```

No Jquery, if possible.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Use `RegisterStartupScript` instead of `RegisterClientScriptBlock`. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/666519/difference-between-registerstartupscript-and-registerclientscriptblock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to include the window.onload in your script file. something like this..

```
StringBuilder script = new StringBuilder();
script.Append("var existingHandler = window.onload;");
script.Append("window.document.body.onload = function(){ confirmPwdChange(); if (existingHandler){ existingHandler()}}");
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(typeof(Page), 
                                           "Script", script.ToString(), true);
```

this ensure, your change password is called on page load and retains any other existing handlers declared already on the page.

Comment: I'm getting this error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`.

Comment: my bad. corrected the code to not include <script> tags

Comment: Now I'm getting the error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: changePassword is not defined at window.onload`

Comment: I gave as a reference method name, replace the changePassword to confirmPwdChange in the server code. updated the snipet

Comment: It executed but, the same problem as it executed before the page completely loaded. While the alert was displayed, page went blank then loaded.

Comment: this could be apossible reason what the behavior. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485244/window-onload-seems-to-trigger-before-the-dom-is-loaded-javascript Modified the code snippet to accomodate the fix.

Comment: I restarted the computer. Now your code is working. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [PageRequestManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397523.aspx)

[List of PageRequestManager events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311028.aspx)

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

// beginRequest: before postback to server
prm.add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);

// endRequest: after postback to server
prm.add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);

function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    // do stuff
}

function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Can you please show how to link this to the success/failure of the code executed in the code behind.